# Why Socrates thinks there arent Forms of mud and hair?

Tags: metaphysics, plato, idealism, parmenides

In the dialogue Parmenides, when Parmenides asks Socrates whether he accepts the existance of Forms of things like Mud and Hair, he refuses it, but i dont get it, what makes those forms unable to be? is it because of their participation of ugliness? (which i beliebe is also denied a form)

Comment: See [Plato’s *Parmenides*:  Socrates’ Speech: The Theory of Forms](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plato-parmenides/#SocSpeTheFor128): "Sensible things are impure inasmuch as they can (and, in fact, often do) have contrary properties. Forms cannot have contrary properties."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the answer of Parmenides when he says everything is valuable but people ignore their importance.
Socrates is young and Plato puts these word in his mouth to show him being wrong as an unsophisticated young seeker of knowledge.
In fact, everything is a representation of the truth in this world and every being has its ideal even the things we think of as worthless.